# How to access application objects from jquery plugin

Tags: jquery

In our application we are caching some frequently used data. Recently we have developed a jquery plugin for our web app. Some of the plugin methods needs to access application cache. 
I tried to access the cache, and result is undefined.

For example:

**Application Class**

```
Application(){
cachedObjects = {};
}
```

---

```
<body>
$(function(){
Application();
});
```

**Plugin:**

```
(function( $ ){

var methods = {
initialize : function( options ) { },
getDataFromCache : function() { 
var data = Application.cachedObjects.someObject;// Here, data is undefined.
 }
};

 $.fn.menuPlugin = function( method ) {
 if ( methods[method] ) {
  return methods[ method ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
 } else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) {
  return methods.initialize.apply( this, arguments );
} else {
}    

};
})( jQuery );
```

How can i access those application objects?

Any suggestions would be appreciative.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many problems here. First you define a function without the `function` keyword. Second you declare `cachedObjects` without the `var` keyword, so it becomes global. I think what you mean is

```
function Application(){
    var cachedObjects = {};
}
```

In any case `cachedObjects` will only be a local variable inside `Application`, not a property of the `Application` object (which happens to be a function).

You can declare an `Application` object in a much simpler way with

```
var Application = {
    cachedObjects: {}
};
```

In any case, if you are developing a jQuery plugin you should not create a global variable `Application`; you can use a variable local to your plugin like

```
(function($) {// All the definition of your plugin goes in this function
    var Application = ...
})(jQuery);
```

or store the cached data in a closure.